# Combine three equally likely observed PDFs describing carrot sizes in a carrot farm

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, python, inference

I observe things so that, during an observational session, I develop a probability density function $f(x)$ describing the likelihood that $x$ is equal to different real numbers. I have $n$ of these observed probability function $[f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n]$. All of these observations seem equally valid to me. How can I combine these into a single probability function, describing the likelihood that $x$ is really different numbers given all of these data?

Another way to think about it is with a somewhat contrived example. Imagine I want to know the distribution of the sizes of carrots currently in my organic carrot farm, so I can advertise statistics about how big they are. In fact, I want to know the exact shape of the carrot size distribution. My farm is huge, so I can't measure them all. I choose three parcels of land and measure 1000 carrots in each parcel, only recording the density functions of carrot sizes found during each measuring session. Since this is all the information I'm willing to invest in, I have to estimate a probability distribution for the entire farm using only this information. I think all three of the measured density functions are equally likely to describe the true carrot size distribution.

Here is a coded example for $n=3$. Some commenters suggested I try averaging; it is not clear to me if that is the right approach. If I choose to average them, I have two options. I can divide the $x$ axis into small rectangles and find the average $f$ value for every $\Delta x$, or divide the $f$ axis into small rectangles and find the average $x$ for each $\Delta f$. I want to rigorously approach this problem, and it is not clear to me if one of these methods is better than the other, if that is at all a valid approach, or if there is a better way. <s>My reasoning in exploring convolution is that the average carrot distribution would be $f_1$ + $f_2$ + $f_3$ normalized such that the area under the curve is one.</s> Based on the community's feedback, I now think that this calls for bayesian updating math that I am not sure how to do.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

# Make observations. We only have PDFs, not data. We loose some information
#    by assuming they are normally distributed.
f1 = np.random.normal(0, 2, 100) + np.random.normal (1, 4, 100)
f2 = np.random.normal(0, 2, 100) + np.random.normal (1, 4, 100)
f3 = np.random.normal(0, 2, 100) + np.random.normal (1, 4, 100)
mu1, std1 = norm.fit(f1)
mu2, std2 = norm.fit(f2)
mu3, std3 = norm.fit(f3)
del f1
del f2
del f3

# plot distributions
x = np.arange(-10, 10, .1)
f1 = norm.pdf(x, mu1, std1)
f2 = norm.pdf(x, mu2, std2)
f3 = norm.pdf(x, mu3, std3)
plt.plot(x, f1, label='f1')
plt.plot(x, f2, label='f2')
plt.plot(x, f3, label='f3')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I want is to estimate the "true" distribution that I took these samples from. Here's what that should look like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nsamps = 20000
truth = np.random.normal(0, 2, nsamps) + np.random.normal (1, 4, nsamps)
plt.hist(truth, 400, normed=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear in several ways, not least that you seem to conflate density with probability (they're different). You seem to be observing densities. Can you explain how they arise? Why would you convolve them rather than take an equal-weight mixture distribution (i.e. why not actually average the densities)? Your question might be more readable with slightly smaller plots (placing `m` directly before `.png` will make them half as big each way but perhaps that's too much smaller)

Comment: @Glen_b I showed my best attempt so far. What more can I do? I do interpret densities to be the same as probabilities. I did explain how they arise—I spend individual observation sessions creating probability density functions of what I think the likelihood of $x$ being different values is and I consider each of these probability density observations to be equally likely.

Comment: Also I would like to point out that averaging could be interpreted as adding then normalizing the distributions. Convolution is the correct way to add probability distributions.

Comment: I think you're confused about what a convolution is - it's the distribution of a sum of *random variables*. A mixture on the other hand has a density function that's the weighted sum of other *density functions* - an average. Which is the correct one to use depends on what you're trying to do, which I don't quite get from your question.

Comment: @Scortchi I added an explanatory example where I own a carrot farm and want to know the probability distribution of carrot sizes

Comment: @Scortchi OP is definitely confused about the meaning of convolution, however the question IMHO is very clear (in particular after the carrot example was added, +1) and should be reopened. I voted to reopen.

Comment: The crucial sentence in your carrot example is that you assume that the "carrot farm has uniform characteristics forever". Then I think the correct thing to do is *to multiply* your PDFs (and the normalize). If you observe carrots of around size 10 in summer and around size 20 in fall, then the average will be bimodal distribution with two peaks; it seems reasonable. However, under the assumption that the farm was producing the same carrots all along this is extremely unlikely. Multiplication will yield something centered around 15. You can view it as Bayesian updating. CC to @Glen_b (reopen?)

Comment: 1. The Q is improved but I think will require some further edits. I'll reopen as amoeba asks. 2. You say "I spend [...] sessions creating probability density functions of what I think the likelihood of x being different values is" -- it's precisely this that I wanted explained. If you're giving probabilities of values, you don't have a density, so I want to know what exactly you are doing and it may be necessary to know more about the process of doing it in order to arrive at a probability model for it.  3. while the Q treats density and probability as the same it remains unclear in that sense

Comment: @Glen_b I think your questions show that you suspect that OP does not well appreciate & describe what their *real* application might be about, and this is fair enough. But OP's question as illustrated by the carrot farm example (and by the code) is pretty clear, no? In each "session" some data are collected, empirical PDF estimated (by some kind of smoothing method), then data are discarded. Assuming that the true PDF did not change between sessions, the question is, how to estimate it by combining session-wise PDFs in some manner.

Comment: Here is one question to you @kilojoules that might help clarify the issue. Imagine that the data were not discarded, and you had all the datapoints from all sessions available in the end. Would then the empirical PDF of that combined aka "pooled" sample be what you are looking for? Or not necessarily? In my example above, if you observe carrots of size 10 plus minus 1 in summer and 20 plus minus 1 in fall, such a pooled distribution would obviously be bimodal (one peak at 10, another at 20). Would getting this distribution be the goal?

Comment: @amoeba Yes, I want the pooled sample. It's also interesting to think about what if I thought some observed PDFs were more valid than others. I am curious about the Bayesian updating you mentioned.

Comment: Then: (1) You should average (and normalize) your PDFs and that's it. (2) This is contradicting the assumption that "carrot farm has uniform characteristics forever", so you should either rethink this assumption or rethink whether you really want the pooled PDF.

Comment: @amoeba I thought of another example that might represent my problem a little better. I notice a plume of smoke pass by my window once in a while. I trace it's path using binoculars and maps, and use available weather information to develop a probability distribution of where I think the smoke is coming from, taking uncertainty in my model inputs into account. Every time I observe the smoke, I develop a new probability distribution. After several observations, I want to know where I think the plume's origin is and where I think it is not, expressed as a probability function.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you're separately fitting normal distributions to three samples (resulting from the same data-generating process), & asking how to combine these fits into a single fitted distribution; as if you'd had all the observations in one large sample to start with.

The mean is doubtless estimated from the $n_j$ observations of the $j$th sample, the $x_j$s, as
$$\hat\mu_j = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{n_j} x_{ij}}{n_j}$$
& the standard deviation as
$$\hat\sigma_j = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_i^{n_j} x_{ij}^2 - \frac{\left(\sum_i^{n_j} x_{ij}\right)^2}{n_j}}{d(n_j)}}$$
where $d(n_j)$ is some function of the sample size (commonly $n-1$, equating to an unbiased estimator of the variance). If you've kept all the observations  you can estimate the mean, by the same procedure, as
$$\hat\mu = \frac {\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{i=1}^{n_j} x_{ij}}{\sum_{j=1}^3 n_j}$$
& the standard deviation as 
$$\hat\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{i=1}^{n_j} x_{ij}^2 - \frac{\left(\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_i^{n_j} x_{ij}\right)^2}{\sum_{j=1}^3 n_j}}{d\left(\sum_{j=1}^3 n_j\right)}}$$
But if you haven't it doesn't matter, because it's straightforward to recover $\sum_{i=1}^{n_j} x_{ij}$ & $\sum_{i=1}^{n_j} x_{ij}^2$ from the parameter estimates for each sample.

The above goes for [method-of-moments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/method-of-moments/info) estimation in general, not just for fitting normal distributions.

It's interesting you mention information loss—in fact this is a case where you're not losing information about the parameters by reducing the data to a vector of parameter estimates. When the parameter estimates are jointly [sufficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/sufficient-statistics/info) you can get a sufficient estimate for a pooled sample using just the individual sample estimates. So, for example, with a gamma distribution you can  recover $\sum x$ & $\sum \log x$ from the maximum-likelihood estimates of scale & shape. But if you were estimating the location parameter of a Laplace distribution by maximum likelihood, you'd have to keep the order statistic at least because the maximum-likelihood estimate, the median, is not sufficient.

Comment: This only seems useful for carrot farms with normally distributed carrot sizes. What if I know the carrot size distribution has many peaks and I want to estimate the size that 95% of my carrots are equal to or greater to?

Comment: @kilojoules: Not quite; re-read the last two paragraphs. Anyway, I think you'll need to explain how you're estimating this multi-modal density from each of the individual samples.